# Concatenate multiple strings in regex if seperated by nothing or whitespace

Tags: regex, flexc++

I'm new to regex and I'm currently running into an issue when matching multiple consecutive strings.

I want to match strings: `"this is a string"`. I managed to do that.

However, I would also like to match multiple strings if they are concatenated or separated by only whitespace: `"this""is a string"`, or `"this" "is" "one string"`.

The problem I'm having is that if I try to do that I also match `"this" as "a string"` (note the matched `as` this should be two separate strings).

I'm using flexc++ so I cannot use more fancy regex stuff like lookahead.

Currently I defined a string as (i used multiple different definitions this one seems the simplest):

```
string      \"(.*?)\"
```

and then try to match multiples using:

```
{string}[ \t]*{string}*
```

Comment: In one expression `(?:\"[^"]*\"\s*)+`

Comment: Or like you did in two: `string      \"[^\"]*\"` and then `(?:{string}\s*)+`

Comment: You usually do not need to escape `"`, but maybe in flexc++ it is needed. Does not hurt anyway.

Comment: Thanks! It works on regexr.com but in flexc++ I get `[Error 1] lexer, line 5: unrecognized input (`?') encountered`

Comment: Do you have a link on the manual about regex in flex++? Try removing `?:` like: `(\"[^"]*\"\s*)+`. It is non capturing group, not sure about its syntax in flexc++

Comment: I'll play around with it thanks! [link to user guide](https://fbb-git.gitlab.io/flexcpp/manual/flexc++.html)

Comment: Without trailing whitespaces this would be `\"[^"]*\"(\s*\"[^"]*\")+`

Comment: without the ?: it seems to work! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work `\"[^\"]*\"([ \t]*\"[^\"]*\")*`

Or if give a string definition:

```
string          \"[^\"]*\"
concat_strings  {string}([ \t]*{string})*
```

Comment: Thanks! this works except the `\s` is not recognized, I replaced it with `[ \t]*`

Comment: @rezi I had a `+` at the end. It should be `*`.